# Using ScheduledExecutorService with netty delays packet

Tags: java, multithreading, netty

I'm trying to delay a packet by 5 seconds but netty sends the packet seconds after the `channel.write` is called.

Runnable

```
public class SendInvalidPassword implements Runnable {
    private Player player;
    public SendInvalidPassword(Player player){
        this.player = player;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Sending invalid login");
        this.player.sendPacket(Identifiers.Outbound.Login_Result, Unpooled.buffer(3).writeByte(2).writeByte(0).writeByte(0));
    }
}
```

player.sendPacket

```
public void sendPacket(int[] identifiers, ByteBuf data) {
    if (this.channel.isWritable()) {
        System.out.println("Send: "+identifiers[0]+", "+identifiers[1]);
        ByteBuf d = Unpooled.buffer();
        d.writeByte(identifiers[0]).writeByte(identifiers[1]).writeBytes(data.array());
        this.channel.write(d);
    }
}
```

How I schedule the task

```
service.schedule(new SendInvalidPassword(player), 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

How can I schedule a task without causing packets to be delayed?

Comment: `I'm trying to delay a packet by 2 seconds but netty sends the packet seconds after the channel.write is called.`  and `How can I schedule a task without causing packets to be delayed?`.

Comment: Seems contrary..

Comment: The packets are delayed more than 5 seconds, it sends the packet seconds after runnable is executed.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, `context.flush` was already called before i write that packet. I simply added a new method named `sendPacketFlush` and replaced `channel.write` with `channel.writeAndFlush`, it works now.